# How do I access properties from API in SoapUI

Tags: java, soapui

I run a testcase in SoapUI from Java with testrunner API and pass a PropertiesMap with a key and value.
However this does not get passed to the test and the execution of the XML passed to the endpoint obviously fails.
What action should I take in either the SoapUI project or from the API for this to work as intended?

Comment: Please show some code or other relevant details.

Comment: Relevant parts of code and XML

 // Create map
 public void createProperties(String key, String value)
 {
  PMap = new PropertiesMap();
  PMap.put(key, value);
 }

 // Run the API call
  runner = project.getTestSuiteByName(suiteName).getTestCaseByName(caseName).run(PMap, false);


XML In SoapUI

   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Method>
         <urn:Data>${#TestSuite#key}</urn:Data>
      </urn:Method>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Please update you question with your formatted code, no one wants to look at code in a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently this only works with the insanely expensive readyAPI (formerly SoapUI Pro)
The work around solution is to write a file from Java, call the SoapUI case and have a Groovy script in SoapUI read the file